# Emptying an Array using ImmutableJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, immutable.js

I'm using [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js) with [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [redux-immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable). Suppose I have an initial state which is an empty array of items:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  items: [],
  other: true,
});
```

I can than add an item:

```
case ADD_ITEM:
      return state
      .updateIn(['items'], list => list.concat({id: 1231}))
      .set('other', false);
```

Afterwards I try to empty the array of items using `set` or `updateIn`:

```
case EMPTY_ARRAY:
          return state
          .updateIn(['items'],[])
          // or
          .set('items', []);
```

When I try to use a `state.get('items').toJS()` I get an error:

```
items.get(...).toJS is not a function
```

What is the correct way to empty this nested immutable array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
case EMPTY_ARRAY:
      return state
      .updateIn(['items'],[]);
```

should be

```
state.set('items', Immutable.List())
```

You've assigned to property simple `Array` which obviously doesn't have `.toJS()` method

*Also `update`/`updateIn` methods takes a function as a second argument.*